# How can i add Key in Json response?

Tags: php, json

i want to add `MainGroup` Key to my json respose.

How can i modify my json response ?

```
<?php

    $responseData ='{
        "Envelop":{
                   "level1": [
                              "0",
                              "1",
                              "2",
                              "3"
                    ]
                  }
     }';

    ?>
```

How can i add level1 in MainGroup as Follow in json?

```
$responseData ='{
    "Envelop":{
               MainGroup:{
                   "level1": [
                              "0",
                              "1",
                              "2",
                               "3"
                   ]
               }
        }
}';
```

Comment: First, your string is not JSON (missing quotes on object key), second, you deserialise the JSON, add the value, and serialise it.

Comment: Have you tried anything or read anything relating to your problem? Please show at least some effort in solving it, SO is not code writing service. Also as mentioned earlier your sting is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your json syntax on http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
{"Envelop":{"MainGroup":{"level1":[0,1,2,3]}}}
```

Try to decode responseData, edit your data and encode again.

```
$responseData ='{"Envelop": {}}';

$aux = json_decode($responseData, true);

$aux['Envelop']['MainGroup'] = array(..);

$responseData = json_encode($aux);
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php